# What is the difference between `vanilla Satchmo 0.8.1` and `just Satchmo v0.9.2`?

Tags: python, django, satchmo

What is the difference between `vanilla Satchmo 0.8.1` and just `Satchmo v0.9.2`?

Comment: Please excuse me if the question is silly. But I am new to python and want to know whether they are different.

Answer (score 1):

There have been many changes in Satchmo between those releases so they are definitely different.

Vanilla Satchmo 0.8.1 would refer to an unmodified satchmo version 0.8.1.  Satchmo v0.9.2 refers to Satchmo version 0.9.2, most likely also unmodified.  If you are going to use Satchmo get 0.9.2 unless you have a really good reason not too.  Satchmo is well maintained and often updated.

Comment: Thanks Loarfatron for sharing your thoughts. It helped me understand better.

Answer (score 0):

[this page](https://bitbucket.org/chris1610/satchmo/src/3b464015cc37/docs/) has the release notes for each version. You should be able to find out.
"vanilla" - please somebody, corrects me if I'm wrong - just means the "out of the box" package, so we're talking about the same thing, not a fork.